# Unexpected for loop result

Tags: php

I'm sure this is a stupid question

but i'm trying to make a select box which show `years` but this for loop gives me a strange result

```
<select name="years">
    <?php
        for ( $year=2000; $year <= 2015; $year++ ) { 
            echo "<option>{$year}</option>";
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

it gives me `2.0002001200220032e+63`

but if i change it like this it works

```
<select name="years">
    <?php
        for ( $year=0; $year <= 10; $year++ ) { 
            echo "<option>$year</option>";
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

can someone explain it to me ?

I have discovered now that the code works on firefox  .. bun not on the chrome

Comment: I just tested it out, it gave me the correct results. are you sure this is the code?

Comment: I have tried it and it worked well. You could remove curly bracket `{ }` since it's useless.

Comment: yes .. it is the only code in a php file ... i copied it !!

Comment: when i start the loop from 0 it works !!

Comment: First solution works fine from 2000 to 2015, second solution will give numbers from 0 to 10.

Comment: the code works fine on firefox  .. but in the chrome it gives me that strange result

Comment: Are you making some secret javascript behind  ?

Comment: _"I have discovered now that the code works on firefox"_ - It that's the case, then you can most likely count out your for-loop as the issue. PHP doesn't change behavior depending on the browser since it's executed on the server, not in the browser. And when testing your snippet, it works like a charm.

Comment: you could always try specifying the value: ```echo "<option value=\"{$year}\">{$year}</option>";```

Answer (score -1):

I'm soooo sorry ... it is "JSON Viewer" plugin in chrome once i remove it .. every thing works fine ... thank you